# Give new valors according to variable [Python]

Tags: python

I wanted to translate letters into the valors they need to be, in order to be evaluated. This is what I want to write

```
if v=='A':
   v=1
elif v=='S':
   v=10
elif v=='C'
   v=11
else:
   v==12
```

But I'm sure there is an easier way to make it look much better.
Thank you for answering

Comment: I was thinking something like:                                    if v in ('A','S','C','R'):
 then get the v index and use v=[1, 10, 11, 12][index]

Comment: Use a dictionary, this is exactly what they are best at `{'A':1,'S':10...}`

Comment: Try uing dict it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
d = {'A': 1, 'S' : 10, 'C': 11}
v= 'A'
d[v] if v in d.keys() else 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Like many in the comments suggest, you can use a dictionary where you put the letter as key and the number as the translation (the value). Let's say that you want to translate 'A' to 12, you should write {'A':12}

Comment: Lmao, I totally forget about the dics, thanks

Comment: Can I get upvote or tick please? I'm trynna get my reputation high

Comment: I just did it, but as my reputation is low they dont show up

Answer (score 0):

As the others pointed out you want to use a dictionary. For your example the dictionary is

```
value_dict = {
    "A": 1,
    "S": 10,
    "C": 11
}
```

Additionally, you will want to use the get method with a default value to retrieve a value from your dictionary. The default value is returned if the key you try to get is not found in the dictionary:

`v = value_dict.get("A",12) #returns the value of key "A" which is 1`

`v = value_dict.get("Z",12) #returns the default value 12 since they key "Z" is not in your dictionary`